# Two verbs used consecutively

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Is it correct to say

> Tsunami coupling in the code 'helps determine' human casualty

i.e., is use of multiple verbs consecutively correct?

Also, is it 'help determine' or 'helps determine'?

Comment: Your sentence is grammatically correct, but semantically obtuse.  I have no idea what you are trying to say.  I'm not sure what it means to *determine human death.*  *determine* loosely means to conclude based analysis or examination, and I'm not sure that anything called *Tsunami coupling* is capable of determining anything.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that, "By studying Earthquake-Tsunami Coupling scientists are more able to accurately predict the potential cost in human lives for these natural disasters"?

Comment: Help + bare infinitive is correct, other non-modal verbs demand a full infinitive (with *to*).

Comment: @Jim Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: The basic import of this question may not be related to the 'Duplicate.' It's not about the infinitive -- it's more in the class of "is *that that* correct?" and similar Qs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two verbs reference different things: *helps* relates to 'Tsunami coupling' here, while *determine* relates to an abstract "one"; moreover, there's a *to* elided in the sentence as well. Read it as:

> Tsunami coupling in the code helps (**one**) (**to**) determine human casuality.

The verbs there are not actually adjacent. Even if they were, that would hardly matter since they are unrelated.

The sentence is grammatically correct.

meta: If you still find the structure a little complicated, you may want to ask the question on [ell.stackexchange.com](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)